# unable to print data from multiple urls using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver

As to say this code works but problem that i am facing that only one url it scrape the data afterward it through an error as show below in figure help me out from this . it print only one link after it through **session not created** error

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd 
import time 

url = ["https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex---twilight-twinkle/149173.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex---statements/12841.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex/12843.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst---extreme-outlook/124580.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst---lunar-mars/124577.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst/124575.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-stability---coco-jazz/124603.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-stability---magnificent-glow/124602.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-joy/124191.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-joy---paradise/15601.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---vivid-blush/149408.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---kaleidoscope-splash/149134.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0/149062.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---rising-gaze/149611.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-air---twirl/124073.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/gowalk-air---whirl/124074.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-arch-fit-refine---her-best/104092.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-arch-fit-refine/104090.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/glide-step---stepping-up/104086.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/relaxed-fit-empire-dlux---sharp-witted/149007.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/relaxed-fit-empire-dlux---paradise-sky/149274.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gorun-smart/128230.html"]
for endpoint in url:
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument(
        "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver.exe',options=options)
    driver.get(endpoint)
    time.sleep(5)
    image= None
    page_Source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_Source, 'html.parser')
    content= soup.find_all('div',class_='c-product-description-features s-product-description-features row') 

    pid=soup.find('span',class_='product-id').text
    links = soup.find_all('img', srcset=True)
    for link in links:
        img= link['srcset']
        alt=link['alt']

    print(pid ,img,alt)
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason you wanted open different browser session. you can do it using one browser session and navigate your urls. Anyways you are not doing parallel execution. To avoid this quit the driver using `driver.quit()`

Comment: @KunduK is there to open on same browser on multiple urls ??

Comment: see if you are using the correct chromedriver version

Comment: yes i am using latest  chrome driver  yesterday i update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time

url = ["https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex/12843.html",
    "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex---twilight-twinkle/149173.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex---statements/12841.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex/12843.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst---extreme-outlook/124580.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst---lunar-mars/124577.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst/124575.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-stability---coco-jazz/124603.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-stability---magnificent-glow/124602.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-joy/124191.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-joy---paradise/15601.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---vivid-blush/149408.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---kaleidoscope-splash/149134.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0/149062.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---rising-gaze/149611.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-air---twirl/124073.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/gowalk-air---whirl/124074.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-arch-fit-refine---her-best/104092.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-arch-fit-refine/104090.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/glide-step---stepping-up/104086.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/relaxed-fit-empire-dlux---sharp-witted/149007.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/relaxed-fit-empire-dlux---paradise-sky/149274.html",
       "https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gorun-smart/128230.html"]
count=0
for endpoint in url:
    print(count)
    count+=1
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument(
        "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
    #options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    driver.get(endpoint)
```

### ISSUE:

The issue is with the remote debugging port, you already used it with one instance ,

### Solution:

remove that

Answer (score 1):

Define chrome driver instance outside of the for loop.I haven't testes but This should work.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument(
        "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver.exe',options=options)


url = ["https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex---twilight-twinkle/149173.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex---statements/12841.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex/12843.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst---extreme-outlook/124580.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst---lunar-mars/124577.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst/124575.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-stability---coco-jazz/124603.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-stability---magnificent-glow/124602.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-joy/124191.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-joy---paradise/15601.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---vivid-blush/149408.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---kaleidoscope-splash/149134.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0/149062.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---rising-gaze/149611.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-air---twirl/124073.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/gowalk-air---whirl/124074.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-arch-fit-refine---her-best/104092.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-arch-fit-refine/104090.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/glide-step---stepping-up/104086.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/relaxed-fit-empire-dlux---sharp-witted/149007.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/relaxed-fit-empire-dlux---paradise-sky/149274.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gorun-smart/128230.html"]
for endpoint in url:    
    driver.get(endpoint)
    time.sleep(5)
    image= None
    page_Source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_Source, 'html.parser')
    content= soup.find_all('div',class_='c-product-description-features s-product-description-features row') 

    pid=soup.find('span',class_='product-id').text
    links = soup.find_all('img', srcset=True)
    for link in links:
        img= link['srcset']
        alt=link['alt']

    print(pid ,img,alt)
```

---

Or quit() the session after completion of each url

```
url = ["https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex---twilight-twinkle/149173.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex---statements/12841.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex/12843.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst---extreme-outlook/124580.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst---lunar-mars/124577.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-hyper-burst/124575.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-stability---coco-jazz/124603.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-stability---magnificent-glow/124602.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-joy/124191.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-joy---paradise/15601.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---vivid-blush/149408.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---kaleidoscope-splash/149134.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0/149062.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skech-air-element-2.0---rising-gaze/149611.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gowalk-air---twirl/124073.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/gowalk-air---whirl/124074.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-arch-fit-refine---her-best/104092.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-arch-fit-refine/104090.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/glide-step---stepping-up/104086.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/relaxed-fit-empire-dlux---sharp-witted/149007.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/relaxed-fit-empire-dlux---paradise-sky/149274.html",
"https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/skechers-gorun-smart/128230.html"]
for endpoint in url:
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument(
        "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver.exe',options=options)
    driver.get(endpoint)
    time.sleep(5)
    image= None
    page_Source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_Source, 'html.parser')
    content= soup.find_all('div',class_='c-product-description-features s-product-description-features row') 

    pid=soup.find('span',class_='product-id').text
    links = soup.find_all('img', srcset=True)
    for link in links:
        img= link['srcset']
        alt=link['alt']

    print(pid ,img,alt)
    driver.quit()
```